# Confused about passing parameters from JavaScript Ajax call back to controller to render a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**Scenario**: I click on some objects,table rows,etc on my page and I get their IDs for example I click on Providers list and get `provider_id`. And then I click on a **button** on the page:

**Now** I have a service that accepts those parameters and passes back to me a JSON which I want to show it in a Table form in my next page. So this button click is responsible for that.

So the page I am gonna show that Table in it is `Pharmacy/Patients` so I have a 
`PatientsController#index` method.

Now in `JS` side I am doing an Ajax call like this:

```
// provider_id is global var and coming from the clicks on other parts of the page.
//so we have some value like 234 for it.    

$('.personlistbtn').click(function(e) {
        $.ajax({

          type: 'GET',
          data : { 'provider' : provider_id, 'therapeutic_class' : 'all' },
          url: '/pharmacy/patients',
          async: false,
          success: function (data) {
            // not sure what to write in here really.
          },
          error: function () {
              // show some oops error
            }
          }
        });

      });
```

So that makes the call to /pharmacy/patients

Now I am confused how to handle it from there?
PatientsController: Maybe something like this?

```
def index

   if request.xhr?
     @my_json = MyNetHTTPFunction.getMeBackJSON(params)
   end
end
```

`MyNetHTTPFunction.getMeBackJSON(params)` is just a method I have written that accepts the query params I am passing to it ( which hopefully are coming from Ajax call right? and queries the web-service and returns me back the JSON I need to use in my View.

Comment: you need to make a method in your controller(e.g. `def get_form`) and define a match in routes which points to that method. `match '/pharmacy/patients' => "patients#get_form", :via => 'get'`

Comment: And then what? What goes in my index method ? What goes in the new method you suggested ?

Comment: then you have access to those params in patients#get_form method. you can make your http call and parse the json in get_form. create a view in `/app/views/patients/_myform.erb` and render it as partial `render :partial => 'patients/myform'` in get_form method. patients#index you will probably have other purpose to use. maybe listing patients ? having another method is a better approach. cause you just want to render a form.